# Convert decimal aggregation into days and hours in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, formatting, dax, numeric, days

I have a numerical column in Power BI and I display the average of it in a KPI card. It updates every day with data refresh. Is there any way to display the aggregated decimal number in days and hours like 3.5 should be 3 days and 12 hrs.

I also have a calculated measure which also gives me the same result in decimal, and I want that also to be displayed in days, and hours.

Comment: How accurate do you want it to be? Only minutes or also seconds if applicable?

Comment: Not even minutes and seconds. Only days and hours.

Comment: @ZygD hey is it possible to get minutes as well?

Comment: Hi. Yes. In the provided answer you should add `FORMAT(_mean,"nn")` . Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax#custom-datetime-formats) for more info on how to use `FORMAT()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way how you could approach it.

Sample table "tbl1":
[image]

`AVERAGE(tbl1[col1])` evaluates to 3.33...
`AVERAGE(tbl1[col2])` evaluates to 3.5

Measure for col1:

```ml
avg_col1 = 
VAR _mean = AVERAGE(tbl1[col1])
RETURN INT(_mean) & " days " & FORMAT(_mean,"hh") & " hours"
```

Measure for col2:

```ml
avg_col2 = 
VAR _mean = AVERAGE(tbl1[col2])
RETURN INT(_mean) & " days " & FORMAT(_mean,"hh") & " hours"
```

Resulting cards:
[image: card type visualizations]